# UISwipeGestureRecognizer not working in iOS 4.3

Tags: iphone, ios, xamarin.ios, ios4

This code worked fine in prior iOS versions but now in iOS 4.3 it's no longer working.  Anyone have any suggestions on what needs to be corrected?

In the FinishedLaunching event I call AddSyncGesture and then whenever the device is rotated I have a notifier that calls the method as well as vertical changes with the orientation change so I have to remove and re-add it.

```
        UISwipeGestureRecognizer sgr = null;

    public void AddSyncGesture()
    {
        try {
            if (sgr != null)
                window.RemoveGestureRecognizer(sgr);
            else
                sgr = new UISwipeGestureRecognizer();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.LogException(ex.Message, ex, "AddSyncGesture");
        }
        try {
            sgr.NumberOfTouchesRequired = 2;
            if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.Orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.LandscapeRight || UIDevice.CurrentDevice.Orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.LandscapeLeft)
                sgr.Direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left | UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right;
            else
                sgr.Direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Up | UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Down;
            sgr.Delegate = new SwipeRecognizerDelegate();
            sgr.AddTarget(this, SwipeSelector); 
            window.AddGestureRecognizer(sgr);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.LogException(ex.Message, ex, "AddSyncGesture");
        }
    }

    Selector SwipeSelector
    {
        get { return new Selector("HandleSwipe"); } 
    }

    [Export("HandleSwipe")]
    public void HandleSwipe(UISwipeGestureRecognizer recognizer)
    {
        if (Utils.CanSync)
            Application.Synchronizer.Synchronize(true,Application.ProgressView);    
    }

    class SwipeRecognizerDelegate : MonoTouch.UIKit.UIGestureRecognizerDelegate
    {
        public override bool ShouldReceiveTouch (UIGestureRecognizer recognizer, UITouch touch)
        {
            return true;
        }   
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use. Not sure it's the only possible way but works with no problems:

```
    protected void InitRecognizers()
    {
        var _swiperRight = new UISwipeGestureRecognizer();
        _swiperRight.Direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right;
        _swiperRight.AddTarget(this, new MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Selector("SwipeNext"));
        this.View.AddGestureRecognizer(_swiperRight);
    }

    [Export("SwipeNext")]
    public virtual void Swipe(UIGestureRecognizer rec)
    {
        //your code here
    }
```

Comment: Will it still work if you set the number of touches required to 2?

Comment: Yes it works still with no problems. I tried it on my real device with version 4.3.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep looking into it.  I actually add my GR to the window in the FinishedLaunching event so it's available app wide. Worked in pre-4.3.

Comment: After further review it looks like swipe left/right works but not UP or DOWN.

Comment: For swiping up and down I use the same logic and it works with no problem. I have noticed that monotouch has sometimes problems with GC. So try to store your recognizers in local variables of your controller. If this does not help than I suppose there is something wrong in your code.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check. Yes, I've had to code around the aggressive GC in my app as well.  Thx